# Braintree error code 91577

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree

When using braintree, with JavaScript and PHP, I have so far managed to validate inputs from a form using PHP, then if there are no errors use Braintree's api in the sandbox.

I get an error code `91577` which is `Merchant account does not support payment instrument`.

#### My PHP code :

```
if($result->success) {
    if($result->transaction->id) {
        $braintreeCode=$result->transaction->id;
    }
} elseif($result->transaction) {
    echo '{"OrderStatus": [{"status":"2"}]}';
} else {
    echo '{"OrderStatus": [{"status":"0"}]}';
}
```

#### My JS code :

```
$.each(data.OrderStatus, function(i,data)   {
    var HTML; if(data) {
        if(data.status == '1') {
            HTML="Order <span>"+data.orderID+"</span> has been created successfully.";
        } else if(data.status == '2') {
            HTML="Transaction has been failed, please use other card.";
        } else {
            HTML="Your card number is not valid, please use other card.";
        }
        $("#orderInfo").html(HTML);
    }
});
```

My question is, what does this *actually* mean (`reworded`), and how could I go about solving this?

---

### --- solved ---

the card number is not valid.

Comment: It sounds like your merchant account isn't setup to handle whatever kind of payment is being entered. I would contact support, they are better equipped to handle this kind of issue.

Comment: Its fine, I found the solution and now my site is fully functional, I will put the answer on here now